# Widget not updating when Activity content changes in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, broadcastreceiver

I have a widget whose content is very similar to what is seen in the actual app, i.e. images and text just on a smaller scale.

I am using the following code to make the widget update after the activity UI updates - only it is not working and the widget it not updating:

```
Intent i = new Intent(mContext, ExtensionOfAppWidgetProvider.class);
i.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
mContext.sendBroadcast(i);
```

I cannot get the onUpdate() of the AppWidgetProvider class to be called without removing the widget and then placing it back on the homescreen.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was the culprit...a couple lines of code were missing from the onReceive() of my AppWidgetProvider class.

```
AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

int[] ids = mgr.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, PromoStackWidgetProvider.class));

for(int id : ids) {
        mgr.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(id, R.id.stack_view);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your widget has itself as a registered broadcast reciever in your AndroidManifest.xml